# Pod image Update and restart container keep same IP question

Tags: kubernetes

I am using a POD directly to manage our C* cluster in a K8s cluster, not using any high-level controller. When I want to upgrade C*, I want to do an image update. Is this a good pattern to update image for an upgrade?

I saw the high-level deployment controller support image update too, but that causes the POD to delete and recreate, which in turn causes the IP to change. I don't want to change the IP and I found if I directly update the POD image, it can cause a restart and also keep the IP. This is the exact behavior I want, is this pattern right?

Is it safe to use in production?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can follow the K8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#updating-statefulsets) for a more 'production ready' upgrade strategy. Basically, use the `updateStrategy=RollingUpdate`:

```
$ kubectl patch statefulset cassandra -p '{"spec":{"updateStrategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate"}}}
```

and then update the image:

```
$ kubectl patch statefulset web --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/image", "value":"cassandra:next-version"}]'
```

and watch your updates:

```
$ kubectl get pod -l app=cassandra -w
```

There's also [Staging the Update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#staging-an-update) in case you'd like to update each C* node individually, for example, why if the new version turns out to be incompatible, then you can revert that C* back to the original version.

Also, familiarize with all the Cassandra release notes before doing the upgrade.